# How to avoid overlapping nodes in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato, image-graphviz

I am trying to draw a graph with many nodes and edges.

However, the graph is becoming too clumsy, with nodes and edges overlapping. I tried (unsuccessfully), the following, all or combinations of these.

```
size = "12.0, 20.0!";
margin  = 0.0;
len = 1.0;
```

I am using `neato` to generate a png file.

The size specification did not even seem to work.

Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using sfdp or fdp from the same graphviz package.   This tools have two parameters  *K* and *repulsiveforce*  which control how far the nodes will be from each other.

Look  [here](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#a:K) for further details

Comment: Looks like the K and repulsiveforce parameters work like magic wands. Thanks a lot.

Comment: K seems to have disappeared?

Answer (score 15):

Try using SFDP using `graph [ overlap=false ]`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Fireblade He did provide an answer - solved my problem with SFDP. I made a slight amendment to improve his answer.