# how to sort a graph and make it look reasonable

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Given: a directed graph dataset 
Node(node_id,x_position,y_position) Edge(start_node,end_node)

node_id, and edge are certain, only one node set as start node, position of this node is certain, let it be (0,0), others' x and y position will be created randomly.

what I need is to sorting every node by row and Columns(reassign the x and y position) so that the whole graph looks reasonable, I mean, the edges will not cross too much.(since the edges must be straight line, crosses can not be avoid but can be minimize )

I have done the first step to divide the graph to many rows by BFS and the edges can only direct to bottom.
Now I need help to sorting the nodes on every row.
Or if you have any idea to sorting the whole graph, welcome.

Comment: How do your rows and columns relate to the graph? are they the `x_position,y_position`? "sorting every node by row and Columns" doesn't make much sense. Are you asking about assigning values to `x_position,y_position` such that crossings are minimised?

Comment: Do your edges have to be single straight lines?

Comment: yes you did understand my need. and the edges must be single and straight line.

Comment: see this [Logic to strategically place items in a container with minimum overlapping connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901490/2521214) beauty (make sure to click on the example there to see visually how it works and the layout result).